# like android application page in facebook from application itself

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Is it possible that a user using android application can like that application page created in Facebook from application itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Just create a Layout with a WebView

Like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Create a activity

Like.class

```
WebView webview;
Then add the following at the end of the onCreate() method:
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl(YOUR_FB_LIKE_URL);
```

Comment: yes I know that WebView thing. But isn't there any way like, when a user clicks the button, he or she automatically likes the page without leaving the screen? In my app, User log in-log out as per wish, but when I put webview, again in that opened page of app, user has to logged in.

Comment: Thanks guys, how do I know what my FB_LIKE_URL is?

Comment: What is FB_LIKE_URL ?

Answer (score 1):

I have this code fo publishing info about my app on the wall:

```
protected void onClickFacebook() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    String Url = Constants.URL_FACEBOOK;
    i.setData(Uri.parse(Url));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

I think if you replace URL-facebook by your like url it should also work

Comment: very late!!! but is that a callback method? or any help from the new documentation?