# How to "like" a page on Facebook from and Android Application?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Hi friends I have an one issue, how to likes a page in Facebook from my application?? I am able to retrieve all the information of Facebook page using page id, also i am able to comment to the page wall, my requirement is that would be able to likes a page in Facebook which i am unable to do..??.I have gone through graph API but unable to find solution..??

I tried this code

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyApp.this, "",
                    "please wait..", true, true);
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
    mAsyncRunner.request("PAGE_ID/likes",params,"POST",new UploadListener(), null);


public class UploadListener implements RequestListener {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            System.out.println("THE RES IS : "+response);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
```

once i run this code it gives error THE RES IS :

```
{
  "error": 
  {
    "message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 3
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Facebook documentation for Pages has been updated and is current (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/). You cannot like a Page via the Graph API, even though you can read the like count information.
There are not an API for it, you can try this.
[like android application page in facebook from application itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766616/like-android-application-page-in-facebook-from-application-itself)

Comment: ya +1, Netwts webview thing is correct, but if i use it user has to login once again...is there any way to like when user click a button, without leaving the page the fb page like count should increase.