# Titanium facebook like button

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, facebook-like

I try to publish like for page from my Titanium Alloy application.

```
var fb = require('facebook');
fb.appid = "1234567890";
fb.permissions = ['public_profile', 'email', 'publish_actions'];

fb.addEventListener('login', function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        Ti.API.info('LOGIN : Logged In');
    } else if (e.error) {
        Ti.API.info('LOGIN : ' + e.error);
    } else if (e.cancelled) {
        Ti.API.info('LOGIN : Canceled');
    }
    publishLike();
});

function publishLike() {
    var dict = {
        access_token : fb.getAccessToken()
    };
    fb.requestWithGraphPath('/' + 'somePageId' + '/likes', dict, 'POST', function(e) {
        if (e.success) {
            Ti.API.info('publishLike : Success!');
        } else {
            if (e.error) {
                Ti.API.info('publishLike : ' + e.error);
            } else {
                Ti.API.info('publishLike : Unkown result');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But error appeared when app make API call:

```
[ERROR] :  FacebookModule: (Thread-1559) [9475,21411] Request error for '/somePageId/likes' call: (#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.
[ERROR] :  FacebookModule: com.facebook.android.FacebookError: (#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.
[ERROR] :  FacebookModule:  at com.facebook.android.Util.parseJson(Util.java:303)
[ERROR] :  FacebookModule:  at facebook.TiRequestListener.onComplete(TiRequestListener.java:88)
[ERROR] :  FacebookModule:  at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:276)
[INFO] :   publishLike : (#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.
```

Do you have any ideas how to publish like?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702355/how-to-like-a-page-on-facebook-from-and-android-application) you cannot like pages from the Graph API. That is because you can only like an Open Graph object with the API but pages are no Open Graph objects.