# Easy Facebook Android SDK : How to like a Page

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-android-sdk

I am using `Easy Facebook android SDk v2.3`. I could successfully access a page and get `details` of page including `number of likes`.

I am trying to implement `like button` in the app using `setLikes(String likes);` method of `Page` class but getting confused with what is to be passed as the parameter.

**Sample Code :**

```
  p = Global.graphApi.getPage("Page ID");
  p.setLikes(String likes);  //what should likes be replaced with, replacing it with user id didn't work
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried with Page ID ?

Comment: No, i replaced Page ID with actual page's id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the facebook documentation, ([Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)), you cannot **like** a Page via Graph API, even though you can read the like count information.

User, have to press the like button himself to like the page.

The accepted answer here may help you: [like android application page in facebook from application itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766616/like-android-application-page-in-facebook-from-application-itself)

Comment: Yeah, went through that..but then, just out of curiosity, can u explain me what's the use of `setLikes` method in easy facebook android sdk?

Comment: Well I'm not sure of this- have not used the android sdk much